# Does a log-concave function on a convex set extend continuously to the boundary?

Tags: convexity, real-analysis, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Let $U$ be an open convex set in a locally convex space $X$, and let $f : U \to [0,1]$ be a log-concave function on $U$ (i.e., bounded and real-valued).  Under what conditions does $f$ have a continuous extension to the closure $\overline U$?

Comment: My simple-minded reaction to this is to study $F = e^{-f}$, which is convex and bounded (if you assume the image of $f$ is in $[0,1]$). The properties of convex functions are rather well known.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, Deane.  Here it's that $-\log f$ is convex, not $\mathrm e^{-f}$.  Originally, I had phrased the question in terms of convex functions instead.  Since $-\log 0 = \infty$, though, I figured the question would be clearer if I just asked the log-concave version.  You're right: this question translates to one about convex functions, which I also do not know the answer to.

Comment: Define $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = \mathrm e^{-1}$.  I don't understand the point of your example; perhaps you misunderstood my question?

Comment: Tom, sorry for the dyslexic comment.

Comment: No problem, Deane.  It was a good suggestion in intent, and will perhaps help somebody answer the question.

Comment: ok, i see that you meant "extension", and $e^{-1/x}$ can be extended as per your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see how $\log$-concavity should imply any form of continuity. For instance, if $\|\cdot\|$ is any semi-norm on the locally convex space $X$ then $f(x) = e^{-\|x\|}$ will be bounded and $\log$-concave but it will only be continuous if the semi-norm is continuous.

What you really want in order to be able to extend $f$ to the boundary of $U$ is uniform continuity and for that the fact that $f$ is $\log$-concave may help but is certainly not sufficient.

Comment: Yes, certainly if $f$ is not even continuous on $U$, then it has no continuous extension to the closure... Perhaps the wording of the problem needs to be changed.

